# How to use Cloud Vision API Export model with Open CV program?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, go, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I've exported a model using the Google [Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/). This results in a TF Lite model, or a pb model (SavedModel format) from the Edge export. Neither of these seem to be importable into OpenCV. I'm not sure what's going wrong here. Do I need to convert formats?

I'm basing off this GoCV source [here](https://gocv.io/writing-code/face-detect/).

And calling it like shown here:

```
./main 0 ./saved_model.pb ./test.txt opencv cpu
```

Results in this error:

```
[libprotobuf ERROR /tmp/opencv-20190908-41416-17rm3ol/opencv-4.1.1/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:629] String field 'opencv_tensorflow.FunctionDef.Node.ret' contains invalid UTF-8 data when parsing a protocol buffer. Use the 'bytes' type if you intend to send raw bytes.
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.1.1) /tmp/opencv-20190908-41416-17rm3ol/opencv-4.1.1/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_io.cpp:42: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(param_file, param). Failed to parse GraphDef file: ./saved_model.pb in function 'ReadTFNetParamsFromBinaryFileOrDie'

SIGABRT: abort
PC=0x7fff7e2f22c6 m=0 sigcode=0
signal arrived during cgo execution
```

Comment: see https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API  /  https://jeanvitor.com/tensorflow-object-detecion-opencv/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Vision API uses TensorFlow models, which could be loaded into OpenCV using the [readNetFromTensorflow()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html#gad820b280978d06773234ba6841e77e8d) function, included in the [dnn module](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html). This function loads SavedModel formatted models (*.pb* file extension).

However this will probably not directly work for the code you linked to, as it is expecting a [HAAR or Cascade Classifier](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/de5/classcv_1_1CascadeClassifier.html#a1a5884c8cc749422f9eb77c2471958bc). Those classifiers are very different from TensorFlow models and you will need to do additional changes to the code if you want to test out a TensorFlow model.